# $(x^2-5x+1)^2-(8x^2-40x+8)(y^2-3)(y^2+3)+16(y^8-18y^4+81) > 0$ for all values of the variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Help me to prove

$$(x^2-5x+1)^2-(8x^2-40x+8)(y^2-3)(y^2+3)+16(y^8-18y^4+81) > 0 \ \forall x, y$$

Comment: Have you tried expanding the expression?

Comment: @Rise No thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(x^2-5x+1)^2-2\cdot(x^2-5x+1)\cdot4(y^2-3)(y^2+3)+\{4(y^2-3)(y^2+3)\}^2$$

Set $x^2-5x+1=a,4(y^2-3)(y^2+3)=b$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to spread out it is now

Answer (score 2):

after simplification we get $$\left(x^2-5 x-4 y^4+37\right)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Plugging
$$(x^2-5x+1)^2-(8x^2-40x+8)(y^2-3)(y^2+3)+16(y^8-18y^4+81)$$
into [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E2-5x%2B1%29%5E2-%288x%5E2-40x%2B8%29%28y%5E2-3%29%28y%5E2%2B3%29%2B16%28y%5E8-18y%5E4%2B81%29), we get
$$(x^2-5x+1)^2-(8x^2-40x+8)(y^2-3)(y^2+3)+16(y^8-18y^4+81) = \left(x^2 - 5x - 4y^4 + 37\right)^2.$$

Now, use the fact that the square of a real number is always nonnegative.